# EF Core call stored procedure and get list of entity

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I use EF Core and SQL Server local for my ASP.NET Core backend. In SQL Server, I have a long complex parametizered stored procedure with multiple joins.

I call it like this:

```
[HttpGet("plantpl/{plantId}&{year}&{costAccTypeId}")]
public IActionResult GetPlantPl(long plantId, int year, long costAccTypeId)
{
    SqlParameter plantIdParam = new SqlParameter("@PlantId", plantId);
    SqlParameter yearParam = new SqlParameter("@Year", year);
    SqlParameter costAccTypeIdParam = new SqlParameter("@CostAccTypeId", costAccTypeId);
    
    var plantPLRows = DataContext.PlantPLRows.FromSqlRaw("PlantPl @PlantId, @Year, @CostAccTypeId",
            plantIdParam, yearParam, costAccTypeIdParam);

    return Json(plantPLRows);
}
```

In order to use the `FromSqlRaw` method, I had to create a model class `PlantPLRow` and the corresponding DbSet `PlantPLRows`.

Basically, I just want to get some data back from the database and send it to the client. I don't want a new `DbSet` nor migration for this. But to use the `FromSqlRaw` I have to use it.

So my question: is this the right way for my situation?

Comment: Yes, that is the way to do it with EF Core

Answer (score 0):

@Sergey, the API call, it's signature/attribute and the controller code are fine and reached, no need to change.

[This](https://erikej.github.io/efcore/2020/04/06/query-non-table-classes-raw-sql.html) blog post from @ErikEj gave the hint. I had to add this lines of code to my `DataContext` class:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<PlantPLRow>().HasNoKey();
}
```